# Custom attributes of checkboxlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-attributes

I added some custom attributes to checkboxlist, but I wonder why I failed to retrieve the values of custom attributes. It will be something like this post [jQuery - find control using custom attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386810/jquery-find-control-using-custom-attribute). But what I want is retrieve through auto postback and code behind.

```
int temp = 0;
foreach (DataRow rows1 in ds_ss_equipments_data.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    cblEquip.Items.Add(new ListItem(rows1["name"].ToString() + " " + rows1["quota"].ToString() + " X " + rows1["price"].ToString(), rows1["id"].ToString()));
    cblEquip.Items[temp].Attributes["price"] = rows1["price"].ToString();
    cblEquip.Items[temp].Attributes["id"] = rows1["id"].ToString();
    cblEquip.Items[temp].Attributes["quota"] = rows1["quota"].ToString();
    temp += 1;
}



foreach (ListItem li in cblEquip.Items)
{
    if (li.Selected)
    {
        equip += (Convert.ToDecimal(li.Attributes["price"]) * Convert.ToInt32(li.Attributes["quota"]));     
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ListItems attributes in a DropDownList are lost on postback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313447/listitems-attributes-in-a-dropdownlist-are-lost-on-postback)

Comment: You might want to use [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3099755/284240) to enable your ListItem's attributes to be serialized in ViewState. Anyway, this is a duplicate from that question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link provided by Tim will probably solve your problem. Just a note on your programming style. This `temp` variable looks very strange. Try this

```
foreach (DataRow rows1 in ds_ss_equipments_data.Tables[0].Rows) 
{                              
    var listItem = new ListItem(rows1["name"].ToString() + " " + ...)
    listItem.Attributes["price"] = rows1["price"].ToString(); 
    listItem.Attributes["id"] = rows1["id"].ToString(); 
    listItem.Attributes["quota"] = rows1["quota"].ToString(); 
    cblEquip.Items.Add(listItem); 
}
```

It is easier an more comprehensible.

And replace this

```
rows1["name"].ToString() + " " + rows1["quota"].ToString() + " X " + rows1["price"].ToString()
```

By this

```
String.Format("{0} {1} X {2}", rows1["name"], rows1["quota"], rows1["price"])
```

Creating an item will look much prettier like this

```
string caption = String.Format(
    "{0} {1} X {2}", 
    rows1["name"], 
    rows1["quota"],
    rows1["price"]
);
var listItem = new ListItem(caption, rows1["id"].ToString())
```